# How to read Assembly Opcode Reference?

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code, opcode, instruction-encoding

I want to make Assembly compiler. To do that, I should make research about Assembly opcodes, so I found this on the Web. When I test to compile some codes with NASM, like this:

```
add eax, eax
```

It outputs this on Binary:

> 6601C0

However, when I see the reference of Assembly Opcodes, it displays this screen:
[image: Snapshot]

Where ADD opcode is 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05.
Which opcode is right? Can I use all of them, or should I use 01 (based on binary compiled with NASM).

Comment: You need to use the opcode that matches the operands used. You should download the Intel manuals and read the first two volumes, especially the second which has all the details about how instructions are encoded.

Answer (score 8):

What you found is just some reference that someone on the Internet put together. **The** authoritative reference comes from Intel and can be downloaded here: [*Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals*](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm).

You obviously assembled the code for a 16-bit real-mode environment (like DOS), where it was assembled to `66` `01` `C0`.

1. Look at the first byte `66`. This is called by Intel "operand-size override prefix" and in your reference "OPSIZE". It changes the size of the operands from 16-bit to 32-bit (`AX` to `EAX`). That is why I guess the environment is a 16-bit system.
2. The second byte `01` is the `ADD` instruction in your reference on the second place in the first line. Your reference calls it `ADD Ev Gv`. The Intel manual calls it `ADD r/m16, r16`. With the operand-size override prefix you can read it as `ADD r/m32, r32`.
3. The third byte `C0` is the "Ev Gv" in your reference (Intel: "r/m32, r32"). Intel calls it "ModR/M" byte. Some bits in this byte define the target("Ev"), some bits define the source ("Gv"). Look at the table "*Table 2-1. 16-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte*" in the Intel manual.

To answer your question: No, you have to use the specific `ADD` instruction for the specific purpose. The `ADD` instructions perform different operations.

Comment: Then what is the difference between EvGv and GvEv? Please explain to me.

Comment: @DanaPrakoso: The definition what is source and what is target. First abbreviation is target, second is source. The abbreviations should be explained in your reference.

Comment: I've never seen this Ev, Gv, etc. notation before. This looks like something invented by that particular reference, which is a poor and confusing choice. It isn't clear to me why they didn't just follow the standard notation used by Intel's documentation, as you mention in your answer.

Comment: Thanks rkhb and Cody Gray, maybe I should re-read the manuals to understand what they are.

Comment: @CodyGray: *I've never seen this Ev, Gv, etc. notation before* - Take a look at "Table A-2 One byte Opcode Map" in the Intel Manual Volume 2B. Thanks for correcting my horrible English :-)